# SQL error with API call

Tags: api, soap

I have a module which extends Magento API (SOAP). I make the call using an external file and everything is fine. When the same call comes from another system (the extension for API is for a mobile app) then I get

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1
>   column(s)

and I don't have any idea what the problem is. 
This is how I call my method:

```
$result = $client->call($session_id, 'customer.login', array(
    'website'   => 'base',
    'email'     => 'denisa@yahoo.com',
    'password'  => '123456'
));
```

Can someone tell what should I verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, enable sql logging (ideally only your API call should run against that server, in order to debug):

In `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`

```
lib/varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

set

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
```

and (if nor already there) create the folder defined in

```
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/sql.txt';
```

Run the API call then have a look at the log file and see what queries ran and why it gives an error.